# How can I change the password of Deja-dup (Backup)?

Tags: backup, password, deja-dup

How can I change the encrypted password of Deja-dup (Backup)?

I have set the encrypted password, it worked in the first two days, but now every time the backup starts it asks for the password I type it but it asks again and again as a result the backup is not taken.
I'm using Ubuntu 11.10.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This question is now 8½ years old. Is it still not possible to change password?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't easily change the password unfortunately.  In order to do so, you must either create a fresh backup in a new location or delete the existing backup files and back up again.

However, it sounds like you may have hit a bug.  Please consider filing a bug at https://launchpad.net/deja-dup/+filebug

Answer (score 0):

Open **Password and Keys** and go into **Login**.

[image]

Select the credential for Deja Dup.

[image]

Reset.

[image]